# User / Rights / Resource management: usage of ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR, ROLE_SUPERUSER, jasperadmin and more?

Tags: jasperserver

(We experienced quite some problems after some rather unconceptional usage of our Jasper Server rights management and **like to share some insights that are not mentioned in the docs**.)

Why should one not rename the role `ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR`, `ROLE_SUPERUSER` or `jasperadmin`?

Which defaults should apply to them?

Which other unintuitive restrictions apply to the rights management (maybe in correlation with repo folder structure, user management, resource management)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(to be continued - feel welcome to edit or move to SO documentation when possible in the future)

admin-specific:

- The **jasperserver code relies on the existance of `ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR`, `ROLE_SUPERUSER`** (not there in community edition, but can be created) **and `jasperadmin`**.
  **Therefore they should not be renamed.**
- users with **`ROLE_SUPERUSER`**, once created, have the opportunity to **`Export`** whole repo-trees by right-clicking on the repo folder in the GUI
- **`jasperadmin` should be part of `ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR`**
- **`jasperadmin` (not the `ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR`!) should have `Administrator` rights on the `/` root node**

  - otherwise the `ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR` does not seem to work as intended and members of it do not have admin rights

overall:

- if one does **not have `ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR`** he **cannot upload input controls**, even if he has `Administrator` rights on the desired folder :-(

  - that's not so nice in a multi-dev environment where a lot of devs work in different areas and should potentially not be complete Jasper Server Admins
- in order to **download/view uploaded files, e.g. PDFs, XLSXs etc. one needs the `read + write` privilege**, because for some reason `read only` or `execute only` are not sufficient (5.2.0)

  - so it seems reasonable to create some subfolder `downloads` in every possible upload location that should inherit this right to its contained resources
- the **length of the internal id path of a resource is restricted to 100 (or so) characters** - if you want to edit some input control that is more deeply nested (you can use it still, but not edit it)

  - thus you should be careful since this could potentially be reached faster on more deeply nested structures
  - creating a folder `/_dev` and then renaming it to `_report-developers` could, e.g. be better since the id path will stay `/_dev`.

best practices:

- (currently we feel that it may be much better to not overuse the Jasper Server GUI and rather embed the reports in a better Document Management System (e.g. Alfresco, SharePoint, WebCenter) than up-/downloading non-report resources or managing users/rights in this quite specific environment)
- it is always good to **not have user-specific rights** at all, but create and think in business roles that should be named as such
- one should ideally **not think resource-specific when designing roles**

  - so -`ROLE_FOLDER_SALES_2016-03`- is not a good practice, rather create e.g. some roles `ROLE_DEPARTM_SALES`, `ROLE_DEPARTM_PRODUCTION` and apply the proper rights on e.g. some folders `sales-2016-03`, `sales-2015-07`, ...
- **short, meaningful repo id paths for some report developer section** are much recommended **since e.g. input controles and other things are shown in `Report Units`** (which are executable within the server GUI) **with their id path instead of there "name path"**
- meaningful naming of input controls or/and their parent folder (to be continued)
- naming of roles (to be continued)
- repo tree layout (to be continued)
- root node renaming (to be continued)

(everything so far is experienced on JasperServer 5.2.0)